# Ionic 2+: Cannot paste into ion-input on Android device

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a new, blank ionic project (v3.20). I add 2 textboxes (ion-input). One inside an ion-item and one not. When I release the project on the browser and open it with an Android device I cannot paste text into the textbox without ion-item around it.
I want to be able to paste text into it. How can I do it with e.g. CSS and without putting an ion-item around every textbox in my project?

```
  <div>
    <p>Not working paste with only ion-input</p>
    <ion-input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"></ion-input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Working paste with ion-item and ion-input</p>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
```

Here you can find an working example:
https://www.wozzol.nl/restfiles/pastetest/index.html

I have already tried: user-select: text; This does not work for the text in the textbox.
I have a bigger project with this problem. In that project paste also doesn't work for IOS. Magically in IOS paste does work for this example.
Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: No. not yet. It already took me a long time to find out the <ion-item> made a difference..